# How do electrons gain energy in a cell?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, work, batteries, electrochemistry

When electrons reach the positive terminal, how does the cell do work on them?
I’ve read in a book that states voltage is literally the push that the cell exerts on electrons, which thus does work on these electrons, as they are moved through a distance.

While this phenomenon is pleasantly intuitive for the name given to the supplied voltage; “EMF”
I still cannot understand why the transfer of energy is described as chemical>electrical.

How does chemical energy play a part in *pushing* coulombs, and thus doing work on them?

Comment: What kind of cell are you asking about? Solar cell? Biological cell? Electrochemical cell? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric cell contains chemicals initially : a cathode Material , an anode and an electrolyte. These chemicals react in particular fashion to generate electrons at the negative terminal, which is then attracted by positive terminal. This attraction is due to potential difference between the two terminals which in other words causes gain in energy of electrons (E=qV). However this is a vague idea. The actual process is complicated and is explained in terms of equations of chemistry and electromagnetism. The chemical energy decreases as the chemical gets used up and battery needs to be recharged (if possible) which changes electrical to chemical energy again .

Comment: Your answer basically says: "It's complicated, so I'm not going to tell you".

Comment: The question is not about the exact process; it s about : 'how do electrons gain energy in cell which is qV . I have given idea of all that is happening. But for details ,ofcourse ,it can be found from various sources. The details don't pertain to the question as I can understand.